# Gibt es bestimmte Formulierungen, wo man "mit mich" sagen bzw. schreiben kann?

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

Ich habe vor kurzem ein Video auf YT gesehen, wo die Sprecherin folgenden Satz ausspricht:

(...) Ich habe dadurch gedacht, dass die Situation nicht nur mit mich betrifft (...)
Der Satz steht in der Minute 6:39 im Video [Hilf mir, 'Deutsch mit Marija' zu retten](https://youtu.be/5qODHl-CsrY?t=399) in YT.

Handelt es sich bei "mit mich" um einen Fehler oder ist es eine bestimmte Formulierung?
Oder hat sie sich sofort korrigiert "mich" anstatt "mit" zu formulieren?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ich habe dadurch gedacht, dass die Situation nicht nur **mit** mich
> betrifft.

In diesem Satz ist das »mit« falsch und muss weggelassen werden. Es gibt aber – um deine Frage in der Überschrift zu beantworten – durchaus Sätze, in denen »mit mich« richtig ist:

> Die Inflation ist eine Entwicklung mit mich betreffenden Folgen.

Answer (score 7):

Dabei handelt es sich einfach um einen Versprecher, den die Sprecherin direkt im Anschluss korrigiert hat.

Answer (score 3):

“Mit” goes with Dativ, and the Dativ is “Mir”. (Ich, mein, mir, mich).

Pollitzer found a clever way around this: “betreffen” goes with accusative (mich). Die Folgen betreffen mich. Mich betreffende Folgen. “Eine Entwicklung mit Folgen”. “Eine Entwicklung mit mich betreffenden Folgen”. So the accusative “mich” belongs to “betreffend” but Pollitzer found a clever way to have the whole phrase following the “mir”.

Answer (score 0):

"Es betrifft mit mich" can be viewed as somewhere between colloquial and lapsus linguae for "Es betrifft viele Personen, und eine dieser Personen bin ich"

Comment: The first sentence is grammatical and totally fine as “mit” is also an adverb. It is used here in the sense given by [Duden under 1](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit).